# Looking for input on an accuracy rate that is different than the exact deep learning compiled code

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, mnist

I just began my Deep learning journey with Keras along with Tenserflow. I followed a tutorial that used a feed forward model on MNIST dataset. The strange part is that I used the same complied code, yet, I got a higher accuracy rate than the exact same code. I'm looking to understand why or how can this happen?

Comment: Are both scripts using the same random seed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Neural network gives different results for each execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45953242/neural-network-gives-different-results-for-each-execution)

Comment: This is the exact code I used, found in this link: (scroll all the way to the end of the post for the full code) 
https://pythonprogramming.net/introduction-deep-learning-python-tensorflow-keras/

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I think I found my answer. It turns out this a common misunderstanding for beginners. I will need to further experiment to thoroughly understand how this works.  
https://machinelearningmastery.com/tutorial-first-neural-network-python-keras/